# Run Python script when Directory is updated

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a script which i want to execute when specific directory is updated. To be more specific: development team have 4 directories (lets say "a", "b", "c" and "d") which they update from time to time. I have a script which take as a parameter name of directory. I wan to execute this script with parameter "a" when directory "a" is updated. Is it Possible to do with Jenkins? If so, can I do same thing using SVN?

Comment: Nothing to do with python. Jenkins must have a SVN plugin that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using python itself, with `watchdog` library.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler 

class FileHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def process(self, event):
        print event.src_path, event.event_type  # print now only for degug

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args[0] if args else '.')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, thats might be really helpfull! However I am not sure if it is better than using Jenkins. These directories are located in server   so probably I should run this script on server side what I dont want to do. Whats more I dont want it to work all time and I want to have simple switch to run or stop it

Comment: Jenkins has a plugin to do the job where this can look for file system changes and trigger a build. But The support ends there, I am not sure if it can pass on the changed directory name to the script.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin